# Images not showing in table with dynamically created HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dynamically creating a HyperLink with an image, and it being entered into every cell from a dataset.
Well for some reason, the images are not showing up in any of the cells, the link is there but the image is not and I have no idea why.
When I stepped through the code, the ImageUrl is correct, and when I copy the path and paste in explorer the image shows up, but its not showing up in the cells.

The code is...

```
for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= 3; cellCtr++)
    {
        HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
       // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
       TableCell tCell = new TableCell();


      /* If the rowcounter is equal to the record numbers
       * then it has to break because if not it will throw an error
       * saying that there is no row at ending position */

           if (rowCtr == rN)
               break;

           string subjectid = myDs.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr]["SubjectID"].ToString();
           string iconUrl = myDs.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr]["IconUrl"].ToString();

           link.ID = subjectid;
           link.ImageUrl = iconUrl;
           link.NavigateUrl = "~/WebForm2.aspx";

           tCell.Controls.Add(link);
           tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

           rowCtr++;
          /* If the cellcount is 3 then it needs to break, if not then 
           * you'll miss every 4rth record, don't know why. But this works */

           if (cellCtr == 3)
              {
                  rowCtr = rowCtr - 1;
                  break;
              }
         }
```

I'm at a loss for why the images won't appear...

Thanks

Comment: check `iconUrl` and match the patch

Comment: I did when I stepped through the code, and its where its supposed to be

Comment: Image may not be present or path may not be correct. Just check using `~` with your path

Comment: Use client side debugger to see the rendered image path.

Comment: Well when I upload the images using the fileupload control, the url that is given in the save as, is the exact path that was in the fileupload, and when I check my database the exact same path is there. I did add the ~ to my iconUrl and when I run that it shows empty images

Comment: I got it working I had to change my stored procedure by adding the IconName to the stored procedure and then changed the Link.ImageUrl to "~/Images" +IconName and now they are appearing. Thanks for the suggestion, would have liked to vote it as an answer.